# How to recreate the IOS calculator layout using auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to recreate the calculator app layout in my app. My problem is that I can't get auto layout to work right. So I have a label at the top and 19 buttons (0 is bigger than the other ones).

What I did:
For label, I control + drag from the label to the top and margins (`Leading Space to Container Margin`, `Top Space to Top Layout Guide`, `Trailing Space to Container Margin`). Then for the bottom part warning, I went and `Update Frame`. This works.

For the buttons I set `Equal Heights` for all of them and `Equal Widths` for all of them expect the bigger button (0). For the buttons from the upper part again I control drag from them to the label and set `Vertical` (I don't want any space between them, and I don't know what to set here). For the buttons from the right I control + drag and set `Trailing Space to Container Margin`. For the bottom ones I control + drag and set `Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide`. Same thing for the left buttons.

I am not sure what to do for the buttons in the middle. I don't want any space between any control, but from the tutorials I didn't saw how to control drag from one control to another and tell it to not be space between them.

Any suggestions how to fix my alignment issues ? I always get: `Need Constraint for: X/Y Position` errors.

Comment: The back ticks are for `code`, not for general emphasis.

Comment: I don't think so, I guessed I exaggerated, but for the auto layout keywords it's ok in my case.

Comment: Now you  can use `UIStackViews`.